# Lusin theorem and Fat Cantor set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

By Lusin-theorem, every measurable function is continuous on a compact subset of their domain, which is endowed with sub-space topology and its complement is nearly a Nullset.

Now suppose we have the indicator function of a fat cantor set. The fat cantor set has measure one half and is closed. The indicator function is constant 1 and will be continuous on the fat cantor set. However, it’s complement has a fixed measure of one half, which cannot be made arbitrary close to a null set. How can I find a close set that satisfies the Lusin theorem?

Comment: The closed set that you want can consist of the fat Cantor set $C$ plus some closed sub-intervals of the open intervals that were deleted when forming $C$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I see, then those „removed“ close set should be a null set? And the continuity is formulated as almost everywhere continuity?

Comment: The indicator function is continuous on the whole set that I suggested.bIt's constant with value 1 on $C$; it's constant with value 0 on the additional closed intervals; and those intervals don't approach any points of $C$, so there's no point of discontinuity in my set.  The closed intervals that I added to $C$ should be a large proportion of the removed open intervals, so that my set has measure very close to 1.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Sorry, I see your point. Just to be sure, there exist a neighborhood around each point in $C$, s.t. the neighborhood doesn't intersect with the closed intervals that we added to $C$?

Comment: That's right. The intervals we add stay a little distance away from $C$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thank you for the help.